# Is there a config to include source files in the debug info?

Tags: kotlin, aop, micronaut, mutation-testing, pitest

Currently trying to get [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/) to work with [Pitest](http://pitest.org/) and it is failing [due to an NPE](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/620) caused by the fact Micronaut does not include the source file in the debug info of the outputted class.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure Micronaut to support this?

[Reproducible sample of this issue](https://github.com/rmaclean-ee/tmp-example-pitest-npe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to configure Micronaut to support
>   this?

In currently existing versions of Micronaut, there isn't.

The classes in question don't have source files, not directly anyway.  Annotation processors in Micronaut create classes to support other classes which live in the project which do have source files.  It is conceivable that the annotation processors could reference the original source files in the generated .class files but offhand I am not sure what the implications of doing so would be.  You are welcome to open an enhancement request at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues.